# jags model throwing error: "Index out of range taking subset of b1"

Tags: jags

I'm trying to specify an occupancy model using rjags and I'm running into an error when it comes to running my model and the problem seems to be related to the specification my year effect which is just a 2D array specifying which sites were surveyed during two years. Each of these units is sampled multiple times, although not the same number of times, range from 3-4 times, and number of sites are 33.

The error I'm getting states 'Index out of range taking subset of b1' and I was wondering if anyone sees a problem in my model. Please see below for my code.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Dodo
[image: Model code]

Answer (score 0):

Near the bottom of your model you define b1 over a loop of 1:2, implying that it must have 2 elements.  The only other place I can see a reference to b1 is 'b1[year[i,t]]'.  It seems that you are specifying year as data, and you have not provided us with this data, but I would expect to see the error 'Index out of range taking subset of b1' if you had one or more element of year that is not either 1 or 2.  You should therefore check your data.

If this doesn't fix your problem then please try to edit your question to give a reproducible example (JAGS code as text rather than an image, and also provide the necessary data and R code to run the model).